# I have a Map data type variable 'Map<String, List<String>>; I want to access the String inside the list non-hard codedly

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

```
final Map<String, List<String>> todoDate = {
///today: [code, read ]};
```

In the body I'm trying to display a Column of the map's key (date) and its values (desired: each value has its own card).

```
body: Container(
    child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(

        //stream listening to the collection 'todos'
        stream: todo.snapshots(),
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          final data = snapshot.requireData;
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return const Text('ERROR');
            } else {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return const Center(child: Text('No todos as of now'));
              } else {
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: data.size,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    for (var key in todoDate.keys) {
                      for (var value in todoDate.values) {
                        return Column(children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                            child: Text(
                              key.toCapitalized(),
                          ),
                          TodoCard(data, index, checktodo, context,
                              todoDate, value, key),
                        ]);
                      }
                    }
                    return const SizedBox(height: 0);
                  },
                );
              }
            }
          }
        }),
  ),
```

TodoCard code:

```
return ....
Text(value[index]),    ///ERROR!
```

I also have a dialog where I add the key (date), and a list of values (todo text)

```
AlertDialog(
...
content: Column( 
2 text fields (1 for date, and other for todo)),

actions: [
OutlinedButton(
onPressed: (){
setState((){
todoDate[dateController.text] = [todoController.text];)
```

These 2 controllers are assigned to the 2 textfields in the alertdialog content.

Comment: Can you include the error message ?

Comment: Look, the first time i add a todo card it works, but then the next time i add, this error message appears:    "RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1"

Comment: Can you include how are adding items and where

Comment: Can you include full widget that will reproduce the error

Comment: I edited the post and added more details

Answer (score 0):

The item you are trying to access  is not out of range, means it is getting null. You can provide default value on cases for text.

```dart
Text(value[index]?? "got null"),
```